# IIS Security Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis

I deployed my webpage (which i build in asp.net mvc) to IIS.

I read another posts in the website about this problem, but it seems that none of them could help me.

But i got this Error : 
**System.SecurityException: Request failed**

[image: Screenshot of error]

I also tried to add the line

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
</system.web>
```

but it didnt help..

Comment: yep.. it didnt help..

Comment: do you use iis7 ?

Comment: its from Server Manager 2012 . i think its iis 8

Comment: I see I faced a similar issue and got help by https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(v=ws.10).aspx But I had the issue on iis7

Comment: hmm i found now that my version is iis 7

Comment: its seems that none of the solutions in the link helped me ..